# How can I plot these in matlab or R

Tags: r, matlab

I have three expressions namely

$\frac{a^2(1-b)}{a+b-ab}+(1-a)a $

$\frac{ab}{a+b-ab}$

$(1-a)^2$

and I want to draw a plot in a-b coordinate when the first one is the biggest in yellow, when the second one is the biggest in blue, when the third one is the biggest in red.(Why latex doesnot work)
How can I deal with that problem.

Comment: R (at least) tends to do better when the function being plotted (I'm assuming some contiguity) is a function of one variable. If you're able to turn them into a function of just `a` or `b`, then it's a bit more straight-forward. As it stands now, that equation is more of a heatmap of sorts, I believe. (I might be wrong, it's been a while since I dealt with plotting formulas like that.)

Comment: ... or is that what you're hoping for, a heatmap?

Comment: This site does not support LaTeX, please use [`code formatting`](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) or plain text. It's unclear how you expect to plot an expression, so this question is currently too broad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't 100% clear, but I believe this is what you're asking for. I've used Matlab.

```
len = 1000;
a_ = linspace(0, 5, len);
b_ = linspace(0, 5, len);
x = zeros(len);
for a = 1:len
    for b = 1:len
        val(1) = (a_(a)^2 * (1-b_(b))) / (a_(a) + b_(b) - a_(a)*b_(b)) + (1-a_(a))*a_(a);
        val(2) = a_(a)*b_(b) / (a_(a) + b_(b) - a_(a)*b_(b));
        val(3) = (1 - a_(a))^2;
        if max(val) == val(1)
            x(a,b) = 0.2;
        elseif max(val) == val(2)
            x(a,b) = 0;
        elseif max(val) == val(3)
            x(a,b) = 0.65;
        end
    end
end
imagesc(x)
colormap('hsv')
caxis([0 1])
set(gca, 'XTick', linspace(0, len, 5))
set(gca, 'YTick', linspace(0, len, 5))
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', linspace(0, 5, 5))
set(gca, 'YTickLabel', linspace(0, 5, 5))
```

I think this is right. I have no way of testing it unfortunately, but hopefully it does what you're after. It's possible I made a typo so let me know if it doesn't work. Obviously you can change parts to suit you.